# I need to put a space inside ng-true-value="fa-li " Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

The plunker shows my list working the way I want. but I am unable to put a space between my list items.

It would be ideal if `ng-true-value="fa-li "` read that space but it doesnt.

I thought about adding spaces like this `{{value}} {{value}} {{value}} {{value}}` but that wont work because if the value is false then there cannot be spaces.

http://plnkr.co/edit/GNrD0rPFjrfRdXSfSF35?p=preview

Comment: `{{ foo ? foo + ' ' : '' }}`. Not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish tho.

Comment: This is made possible out of the box in angularjs `1.3.0-beta.15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't. Just use a function, it's far more reusable and you don't have to change large amounts of code when you add/remove one. See here:

```
$scope.classDisplay = function(){
 var classStruct = {
  'fa-li': $scope.fali, 
  'fa-lg': $scope.falg, 
  'fa-2x': $scope.fa2x, 
  'fa-3x': $scope.fa3x, 
  'fa-4x': $scope.fa4x, 
  'fa-5x': $scope.fa5x, 
  'fa-spin': $scope.spin
 };
 var result = "", keys = Object.keys(classStruct);
 for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  if(classStruct[keys[i]]){
   result += ' ' + keys[i];
  }
 }
 return result;
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XFbbioa2gXf5Om68p35H?p=preview